# Each row is for which label in confusion matrix python

Tags: python, numpy, import, scikit-learn

I am using confusion matrix in sklearn.

My problem is that, I can't understand each row is for which label! My labels are `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

I was wondering if the first row is for label 0, the second one is for label 1 and so on?

For making sure, I tried this code which i thought make the confusion matrix by order of labels. But I got an error.

```
cfr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 80, n_jobs = 5)
cfr.fit(X1, y1)
predictedY2 = cfr.predict(X2)
shape = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
acc1 = cfr.score(X2, y2,shape)
```

Error is:

```
acc1 = cfr.score(X2, y2,shape)
TypeError: score() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)`
```

Comment: What's the documentafion for `crf.score`?

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.score

Comment: The 4 arguments are self and the 3 explicit ones.  I'd try using the keyword on the last.   And failing that check versions.  The keyword argument may be a recent addition.  I don't have that package so can't check myself.  Though I could explore the github code.

Answer (score 1):

`score` gives the accuracy of the classifier, i.e. the number correctly predict per number of examples. What you're looking for is the `predict` function which yields the class predicted for each input. Check out this example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RFC
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

# Add a random state to the various functions so we all have the same output.
rng = np.random.RandomState(1234)

# Make dataset
X,Y = make_classification( n_samples=1000, n_classes=6, n_features=20, n_informative=15, random_state=rng ) 
# take random 75% of data as training, leaving rest for test
train_inds = rng.rand(1000) < 0.75

# create and train the classifier
rfc = RFC(n_estimators=80, random_state=rng)
rfc.fit(X[train_inds], Y[train_inds])

# O is the predicted class for each input on the test data
O = rfc.predict(X[~train_inds])

print "Test accuracy: %.2f%%\n" % (rfc.score(X[~train_inds],Y[~train_inds])*100)

print "Confusion matrix:"
print confusion_matrix(Y[~train_inds], O)
```

This prints:

```
Test accuracy: 57.92%

Confusion matrix:
[[24  4  3  1  1  6]
 [ 5 22  4  4  1  1]
 [ 5  2 18  5  3  2]
 [ 2  4  2 29  1  4]
 [ 3  1  3  2 28  3]
 [10  4  4  3  8 18]]
```

According to the documentation of `confusion_matrix`, the `i,j` component of the confusion matrix is the number of objects known to be of class `i` but classified as class `j`. So in the above, the correctly classified objects are on the diagonal, but if you look at, say, row 3, column 0, it looks like two "class 3" objects were misclassified as "class 0" objects.

Hope this helps!